# On Mac, where can I find git-http-backend?

Tags: macos, git, cgi

To install [Phabricator](http://phabricator.org), I need `git-http-backend` (a CGI script). Though this does not come with Mac's nor HomeBrew's `git`. Where can I find it?

I could probably create a shell script named `git-http-backend` that calls `git http-backend` (that is, call `git` with the command `http-backend`). But how do I deal with the parameters?

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assumed too quickly, that it wasn't there. Shame on me.

`sudo find . -name git-http-backend` revealed the following:

Mac's git:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend
```

HomeBrew's git:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/git/2.0.1/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed git from the official [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/) website and found that it included `git-http-backend` here:

```
/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who installed git via [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org), your `git-http-backend` is located here:

```
/opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend
```